# bootstrap modal body doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

hello everyone i need help. i wanna show dinamic data to bootstrap modal body.

here is my code so far :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Detail</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="fetched-data"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        //menggunakan fungsi ajax untuk pengambilan data
        $.ajax({
            url : 'det_registration.php',
            success : function(data){
            $('.fetched-data').html(data);//menampilkan data ke dalam modal
            }
        });
     });
});
```

the modal windows is open. but, the ajax code is not execute for call det_registration.php and fetched data

what i missed ? thanks for your help :)

update:
i am sorry all. this is the code how i call the modal

```
<a title='detail' href="#myModal" data-toggle='modal'><span class="pull-left">View Details</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what else you have in your code but take a look [here](https://codepen.io/ishio/pen/dWQZzZ).

I've added a button calling to your modal. With the code you provided, it all seems to be working just fine to me.

This was all I added

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn brn-primary">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: thanks for respond :) see my answer. i have already solved my broblem

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is just a peace of code but please provide more information. In this case I don't know how you are opening the modal, this could be the problem.

Your script looks fine, if the ajax function was not executed is because your modal lister could't "listen" the event **"show.bs.modal"** try to put an alert just after the opening of the anonymous function to test it.

If you could't see the alert is because the event was not listened.

Finally, if you are opening the modal via JS, just remember that the function that opens it must exist before it was executed.

Comment: Could  you send an alert just after `$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {` ? this will say us if the problem is the listener or not. In addition, I recommend you to open your browser console, In Chrome use F12 to open it, in the console tab you will see whether is a problem in your script or in your request.

Comment: thanks miguel for your explanation. but i am very beginner in web programming. can you show me how to creat alert as you say ?

Comment: Sure! an alert is called by the function: `alert()` and it will display literally an alert(). This is very rudimentary way to display content and not appropiate for a real envirnment neither for debuging, I used it because when an alert is present it stops the execution of the code until you response the alert. Instead of that you can use `console.log()`

Comment: thank youu you're helping me :). see my answer. i have already solved my broblem

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem. the problem is there is two jquery.js in my php file. the first one is bootsrap jquery.js and the another one is datatable jquery.js. then after i deleted datatable jquery.js, my problem was solved